# .h file not found when compiling a package using Bitbake

Tags: c, yocto

I'm new to Yocto,
I have a library, let's call it Lib1. Lib1 uses interfaces from another library lets call it Lib2.
So I included Lib2 in Lib1 and it compiles correctly.
now I have a binary file that uses Lib1, when building this binary an error  occurred in the Lib1.so "Lib2.h no such file or directory".

The steps that I tried to fix the problem:
I added Lib2 package in Lib1 recipe file:

> Depends += "Lib2"
>       Rdepends += "Lib2"

also in Lib1 Makefile:

> libs = -lLib2
>        Cflags = $(Lib2_cflags)

but it didnt work.

The error message:

> 1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot=  -c -o Bin-main.o `test -f 'main.c' || echo '../../git/Bin/src/'`main.c | In file included from
>   ../../git/Bin/src/main.c:15:0: |
>   /home/build/tmp/work/Bin/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/Lib1.h:32:33:
>   fatal error: Lib2: No such file or directory |  #include "Lib2.h"

Lib1 recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Lib1"
PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = ""

DEPENDS = "Lib2" 

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "Lib2"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev += "Lib2"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"

EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DWITH_SYSTEMD=ON"
inherit autotools pkgconfig systemd

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"

PACKAGES += "${PN}-test" 

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*.so* ${sysconfdir}/* ${libdir}/pkgconfig/*"
FILES_${PN}-dev += "${srcdir}/* ${includedir}/* ${libdir}/pkgconfig/* ${libdir}/*.so"
FILES_${PN}-test += "${bindir}/*
```

Lib2 recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Lib2"
PR = "r1"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

DEPENDS = "" 

SRC_URI = ""

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit autotools pkgconfig


INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "dev-so"


FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/Lib2.so*"

FILES_${PN}-dev = "${srcdir}/* ${includedir}/* ${libdir}/pkgconfig/*"
FILES_${PN}-staticdev = "${libdir}/*.a"
```

binary file recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Binary"
PR = "r0"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
DEBIAN_NOAUTONAME_${PN}-test = "1"

SRC_URI = ""

DEPENDS = "Lib1" 


S = "${WORKDIR}/git/"

inherit autotools pkgconfig systemd

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"

SYSTEMD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "Bin.service"

SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE_${PN} = "enable"
EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DWITH_SYSTEMD=ON"

FILES_${PN} += " ${sysconfdir}/system.d/*"
```

Comment: Show the recipes and the error message.

Comment: maybe try `CFLAGS += $(Lib2_cflags)` as Yocto needs to set its own CFLAGS?

Comment: the problem was solved with two modifications: 1) the ".pc" file of Lib1 was not added in the makefile  2) the Lib2 was written in Cpp and Lib1 in C so we used the key word `extern`